# UIScrollView touch dissipate to Parent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have some Horizontal `UIScrollViews` in my main screen with pictures. My main screen also has a gesture that when you swipe from left to right it shows a hidden menu.

What i want to do is that when I'm scrolling the `UIScrollView` and it reaches the end on the left, I want the touch to go to the parent and show the hidden menu.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   if (sv.frame.size.width = sv.contentOffset.x) {
       sv.scrollEnabled = NO;
   }

}
```

Edit

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   if (sv.frame.size.width = sv.contentOffset.x) {
       [self methodToOpenMenu];
   }

}
```

Comment: partially correct, I do understand the logic, but i have to remove finger then swipe again and also the scroll stops scrolling after and i dont want that

Comment: if you just want to show the menu, then do so instead of playing with the gestures. If you bring the menu to the top of the views layers the touch gestures will work on the menu. I have edited the answer . . .